# How to encrypt user data while keeping it viewable in site manager?

Tags: security, encryption, salt

I am building a web app and want to ensure that we go about encrypting user data the right way.

This data is not highly sensitive (like medical records or CC numbers) but I think it should be stored securely nonetheless - just simply name, company, position, telephone number, email address. And password of course - but this will secured using hash/salt...

I want to store the user data securely to guard against the site being hacked/server compromised. But I also need the customer names, organisations, telephone numbers and email addresses to be visible to the site administrators - ie visible in the back end.

The passwords will not be visible to site admins of course...

I would appreciate some advice on how I should go about this - I want to do enough to be "reasonably" secure without going overboard - like I say the data is not extremely sensitive and the site itself is not one anyone would be embarrassed to be a member of...

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is a process of calculating irreversible (or alamost irreversible) one way function to data. So you probably ment encryption.

As to application level encrytpion in this context you can do this but it will only protect from someone dumping a raw database and reading it. To provide functionality of administrative view you have to encrypt everything with one key. And decrypt it on the fly in your webapp, what is worth pointing out is that if your application is vulerable to SQL incjection this could mean that despite of encryption someone will be able to extract the data. Becaouse your app might decrypt it thinking that is a part of legitimate data flow.

Encrypting data would introduce another problem what with narrowing selects on those fields ? You would have to encrypt params before passing. But you would have to use the same IV to match field values. But in order to use valid IV you would have to know exact record in db from which extract InitializationVector. As i said it can be tricky.

I personally think that encryption is a last resort and should be used only when absolutley necessary. Becouse when solving confidentiality problem it introduces a key management problem which can be bigger. And I think that is your case.